# Animate repositioning of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Are there any jQuery libraries/CSS tricks that can make divs  animate (see them moving from one place to another) when they are automatically repositioned for example if they no longer fit in the window or a media query. I have created a very simple JS Fiddle as a starting point http://jsfiddle.net/22Bxx/ I know it is possible with CSS3 if they are all positioned absolute however I want to do it with inline/relative elements.

```
 <div></div> x8

 div {
     padding: 50px;
     background-color: red;
     margin: 5px;
     width: 25%;
     float: left;
 }
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Isotope should serve you well. It changes your relative divs to absolute positioned divs and animates them from there.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: looks like it could have done what I wanted if I used it earlier, I already have the CSS working perfectly but the layoutModes such as masonry are trying to redo the CSS I have already done